# Authenticate with Javascript, use PHP for offline postings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, token

I am writing this after the offline_access permission has been deprecated, so I'm hoping to get some help with my problem.  I'm also new to Facebook Graph API.

I have created a test page that can authenticate with the JS SDK, request specific permissions, check those permissions, etc...

However, what I would like to know is how to extract data from the Javascript Session variables (namely token) and store them in a database that can be used via PHP to extend the token and use it for offline use.

I'll give you my scenario.  I am contemplating a site where people upload images.  They use Facebook to create an account on my site.  As people vote on the images, points accrue.  When a user accrues a certain number of points, say 1,000 - I would like to post an update on the photo owner's wall something like "John Doe has just surpassed 1,000 points on example.com".

Obviously that action is triggered by a third person event, and as such I don't have a valid short-lived token to post to John Doe's wall.

My only idea is to perform an AJAX call after authorization to an abstraction PHP file that will store the user_id and token, and that abstraction file will handle storing the details in the database and sending out a cURL call to the graph to extend the life of the token, and then update the token in the database.

Is that really the best way to do it?

Also, why the 60 day limit on "long-lived" tokens?  What if John Doe hasn't visited my site in 3 months, but slowly his photo of a cat riding a unicorn has been garnering points, and when it hits a milestone, what better way to get John Doe to revisit my site than by posting on his wall that he's now got 1,000 points.

Thank you all for your thoughts in advance,
HPC

Answer (score 0):

1.As per your first question on how to provide the PHP the user-id and token value setup by JavaScript API you can refresh the page after the user logs into your application so that the PHP can have those values and perform necessary action.
2.And for your second question on how to re-engage a user who hasn't logged in within the life of the long lived token I would like to suggest you to use either [apprequest](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) or [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) to re-engage with him and ask him to visit your site to know his recent achievements.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  After doing some digging last night, it turns out I can generate an app_access_token that is permanent and allows my app to post to any users who have given my app publish_stream permissions.

Unfortunately because Facebook's documentation is so convoluted and different parts are out of date, this app_access_token isn't mentioned in the part of the documentation  you'd expect.  It's actually mentioned in the open graph section.